# How to stop local server with Parcel bundler

Tags: parceljs

I am using API of Parcel bundler to build and start a local server.

```js
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');

let entryFile = ...;
let options = ...;

(async function() {
    let bundler = new Bundler(entryFile, options);
    let b = await bundler.serve();
)();
```

I would like to stop the server at some point. I cannot find this in their documentation. Is there a method that allows me to stop the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a method `close`.

```js
    let bundler = new Bundler(entryFile, options);
    let b = await bundler.serve();

    b.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

From The command line:

use the command : `ctrl + c`

Comment: The question is about using API